# Flex div being ignored on iphone xr

Tags: html, css

I am having issue with flexbox on my iphone xr, on all other models this does't happen, also on android phones this doesn't appear aswell, it looks like the `logo` div flex is being ignored and the form goes over it. Am I missing some important css option?
My code goes as following

```html
<div class="auth">

test
<div class="logo">
test
</div>

<div class="form">
test
</div>
</div>
```

```css
.auth {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.logo {
  flex: 0.1;
}

.form {
  flex: 1;
}
```

[image]

Comment: flex: 0.1 is not a valid entry. Please check this link for better understanding . https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @NavpreetKaur , how it is not valid? 0.1 is 10% and 1 is 100%. even when I set my flex to 0, the same thing happens

Comment: Maybe try setting something like `min-height`. hard to say more without more code.

Comment: Basically what I want is to have the logo in the same place on every view, that's why I tried flex 0.1, put logo inside it and fill remaining content with flex 1. Are there better ways to do this? I just dont want the logo to change space based on the content beneath.